# Scraping an IFrame which has as source a jsp

Tags: c#, web-scraping, html-agility-pack, scrapysharp

I'm new to webscraping and I have to do the following:
1. Go to a webpage
2. Find an element 
3. Get its value

Now I don't have a problem going to the webpage, that works fine.
The problem is that the element I need, actually comes from a jsp which is displayed in an iframe.

I'm trying to get the elemant using HtmlAgilityPack and ScrapySharp.

This is my code :

```
ScrapingBrowser Browser = new ScrapingBrowser();
Browser.AllowAutoRedirect = true; 
Browser.AllowMetaRedirect = true;

WebPage PageResult = Browser.NavigateToPage(new Uri("[The website I need to go to]"));

HtmlNode myNode = PageResult.Html.CssSelect("#WREPBody").First();
string innerHtml = myNode.InnerHtml;
```

This works fine. But it returns the following :

```
<ilayer id="WREPBodyLayer" src="/app014/wrep/rep/gp/jsp/nl/REPGPdata.jsp"></ilayer>
```

Now the actual element I need is displayed using the REPGPdata.jsp I think.
The jsp displays the data as below :

[image]

The element I need, would be next to the label "Ondernemingsnr".
Does anyone know how I could get access to the element I need?

Comment: Can you navigate directly to the URL of the iframe?

Comment: The jsp part is irrelevant to the problem you have. Please remove the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
I just had to browse to the jsp and from that result start scraping again.

Comment: Yep that is normally the easiest way. You can do some things with certain headless browsers but in general you just want to do that.